# How to Group Prototype Cells Dynamically Objective - c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have tried searching that but I can't seem to find an answer so far.

Currently, I populate my data dynamically using prototype cells.

I need to group the cells dynamically according to date.

Let say on 1/1/2001, I have 3 rows. On 2/1/2001, I have 5 rows. I can't seem to find a guide or sample that shows how to group the cells dynamically. Below are portion of my codes.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
 #warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
 // Return the number of sections.
 return 1;
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
#warning Incomplete method implementation.
// Return the number of rows in the section.
return [someArray count];
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath   *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cell";
IssuesViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[IssuesViewCell alloc]
            initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
            reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

// Configure the cell...  
currentSomething = [[Something alloc] init];
currentSomething = [somethingDiscovered objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

cell.typeLabel.text = currentSomething.type;
cell.titleLabel.text = currentSomething.title;
cell.begDateLabel.text = currentSomething.begDate;

return cell;
}
```

Updated on 23/8/2013:

Now I can group it dynamically, however, I am having a problem in displaying the correct data for the cell.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
 #warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
 // Return the number of sections.
 return return [someDate count]; //someDate is an array that stores dates
}
- (NSString*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
// set title of section here
return [someDate objectAtIndex:section]; //set the title of each section as a date
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
#warning Incomplete method implementation.
// Return the number of rows in the section.
return [[someIssues objectAtIndex:section] count]; //some issues hold data to be displayed in the cell.
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath   *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cell";
IssuesViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[IssuesViewCell alloc]
            initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
            reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

// Configure the cell...  
currentSomething = [[Something alloc] init];
currentSomething = [somethingDiscovered objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

cell.typeLabel.text = currentSomething.type;
cell.titleLabel.text = currentSomething.title;
cell.begDateLabel.text = currentSomething.begDate;

return cell;
}
```

For example, object A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K. And I have 4 sections. section[0] suppose to display A, B, C, D, E, F, G. Section[3], suppose to display H, I, J, K.

But right, now, it only displays A, B, C, D, E, F, G in section[0]. A, B, C, D, in section[3]. Please assist.

Solution:

```
someIssue = [[someIssues objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Comment: So you couldn't find anything about grouped `UITableView`?

Comment: Most solution that I found, their sections are static please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of doing this, is to have an structure to populate your tableview and whenever it gets modifies just reload all of your tableview or just part of it.

```
– reloadData //Reload all of your table view's data
– reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation: //Reload some rows
– reloadSections:withRowAnimation: //Reload some defined sections
```

More on how to use those methods can be found on [UITableView Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Your structure can be as simple as this:

```
 //This will represent two sections with two cells each
`NSArray *contentArray = @[@[@"Cell A",@"Cell B"],@[@"Cell C",@"Cell D"]];`
```

That is an array that contains elements that will represent the sections, each element/section is an array as well containing all of the cells values.

And on your TableView's Delegate and Datasource methods you should do this

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    if (contentArray) {
        return contentArray.count;
    }
    return 0;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (contentArray) {
        return [[contentArray objectAtIndex:section] count];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That works for my grouping! But now I am having a problem displaying the data. Will update this page in a few minutes.

Comment: Updated my question page.

Comment: I just needed to edit it to     someIssue = [[someIssues objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
 so that it will display the data that I want.